# Having trouble with object creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program where a user can learn a number of skills which are predefined and are changed to a `learned = True` value later. I want to put all of the objects which are already learned into a list but can't find a way to collect all objects to sort through them and would appreciate if anyone could suggest one. This is my current strategy using a list in the class definition but it isn't working correctly so I would be appreciative if someone had a better way.
My class currently looks like this:

```
class attacks:
learned = False
def __init__(self,name,baseDMG,adMulti,apMulti,accuracy):
    self.name = name
    self.baseDMG = baseDMG
    self.adMulti = adMulti
    self.apMulti = apMulti
    self.accuracy = accuracy
    global adAbilities
    global apAbilities
    global mixedAbilities
    adAbilities = []
    apAbilities = []
    mixedAbilities = []
    if adMulti > 0 and apMulti > 0:
        mixedAbilities.append(self) 
    elif adMulti > 0:
        adAbilities.append(self) 
    elif apMulti > 0:
        apAbilities.append(self)
```

But when I check the items in the lists it only stores one of the objects in the 2nd list and none in the others even though i have created these objects:

```
slash = attacks("slash",20,6,0,90)
smite = attacks("smite",20,0,6,90)
doubleStrike = attacks("doubleStrike",30,9,0,70)
blast = attacks("blast",30,0,9,70)
weaponThrow = attacks("weaponThrow",20,8,0,90)
```

Only the last object defined is the only one in any lists no matter which object is last defined (tested by printing lists after each object is defined).

Comment: You need to indent the class methods and other members of the class. White space matters in python

Comment: Also, since you are bringing the global lists into the init scope, you are making them empty again every time you instantiate an object. Every time a new object is instantiated, you are emptying the global list variables. Declare your empty lists outside the class if they are global

Comment: Thank you very much